# Proper way to set margin between MUI grid items

Tags: css, material-ui, css-grid

I am trying to get some margin between my three grid items. I would like each grid item to take up 1/3 of the container's width. However, neither `spacing` nor `gap` prop is helping me to achieve this.

**Using `spacing`**
It seems like `spacing` only adds padding to each box. And padding is only added to the left and top.

```
<Grid container spacing={5} sx={{ width: 800, border: 1 }}>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
    <div>Box 1</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "lightBlue" }}>
    <div>Box 2</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "limeGreen" }}>
    <div>Box 3</div>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

**Using `gap`**
`gap` creates margin between the grid items but pushes the third box out of the first row.

```
<Grid container gap={5} sx={{ width: 800, border: 1 }}>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
    <div>Box 1</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "lightBlue" }}>
    <div>Box 2</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "limeGreen" }}>
    <div>Box 3</div>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

**How can I achieve something like this?**
[image]

I generated this image by setting each grid item to take up 3 columns instead of 4 (see below). However, it feels hacky. Is there a better solution? I am also open to solutions that don't involve MUI grids.

```
<Grid
  container
  justifyContent="space-between"
  sx={{ width: 800, border: 1 }}
>
  <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
    <div>Box 1</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ backgroundColor: "lightBlue" }}>
    <div>Box 2</div>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ backgroundColor: "limeGreen" }}>
    <div>Box 3</div>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a result like the image, I would suggest to give the background-color in the div inside the `Grid` `item` and use the padding for making it to have some white area on the right (if you don't want to use the spacing as it gives space around the `Grid` item)

```
  <Grid 
  container sx={{ width: 800, border: 1 }} m={2} 
  // spacing={2} decide if you want extra spacing or not
  >
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <div style={{ marginRight: "40px", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
        Box 1
      </div>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <div style={{ marginRight: "40px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>
        Box 2
      </div>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <div style={{ marginRight: "40px", backgroundColor: "limegreen" }}>
        Box 3
      </div>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-robinson-5q32d1?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using MUI `Grid2`'s `disableEqualOverflow`

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2'; // Grid version 2

<Grid container spacing={2} disableEqualOverflow m={1}>
</Grid>
```